# How to add a multilingual support in react js with api call?

Tags: reactjs, api, multilingual

I am trying to add a multilingual support in my ReactJS website, the challenge is that it has to be done by making an api call. Whenever the user selects a language an api call is to be made with the user selected value. I have almost 10 apis that needs to be triggered at the same time.

My locale lang variable

```
import enLang from './entries/en_US';
import daLang from './entries/da_DK';

const AppLocale = {
  en: enLang,
  da: daLang,
 
};
export default AppLocale;
```

[[image: This is a dropdown where user selects language.]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not asking on language translation, and the entries return javascript objects or arrays.

A simple demonstration to change language with select is like this.

```
import enLang from './entries/en_US';
import daLang from './entries/da_DK';
const Component = () => {

   const [language, setLanguage] = useState(en);



  return (
<div>
  <select name="language" onChange={(e) => setLanguage(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="en">DA</option>
      <option value="en">EN</option>
  </select>
<pre>{ JSON.stringify(language, null, 4) }</pre>
</div>
)
}
```